# What madness is this c group of casts

Tags: c, casting

I was looking at this open source boot loader and I saw this line of code.  What is happening on the last line?  Is that some kind of pointer to a function, with a cast to an address?

```
    uint8_t ret = init_api();
    uint16_t ptr;
    ptr = PGM_READ_WORD(JUMP_TABLE_INDEX(6));

    ret = ( (uint8_t(*)(uint32_t, uint8_t *, uint8_t)) ptr )(addr, data, erase);
```

Comment: Madness?? THIS IS C!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`ptr` is casted to a pointer to a function

```
uint8_t f(uint32_t, uint8_t *, uint8_t)
```

and the function gets called with parameters `addr`, `data`, `erase`.

Comment: Note also that the jump table referenced by the JUMP_TABLE_INDEX macro is most likely an array of function pointers, so that macro returns the address, and the last line of the code above actually calls the function referenced by the 6th element of the jump table.

Comment: In cases like this, it's more readable to typedef the function pointer type, then cast `ptr` to that type.